# Como eliminar varios valores con Splice de un LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, formularios, funciones

Creé un formulario para añadir datos mediante sus inputs y sus ID, los datos los registra el localStorage perfectamente pero el error radica cuando intento borrar algún index con la función de ''splice'', la función si la ejecuta pero solo borra a partir del primer index guardado hasta el ultimo, y no al que selecciono.

DATO: Cuando solo se trata de añadir 1 valor al key, la función si me sirve, pero cuando son varios valores no me lo ejecuta como debería.

```
const crearDatos = (nombre, fecha, correo, direccion, telefono, tarjeta, fechaEX) => {
  let item = {
    nombre: nombre,
    fecha: fecha,
    correo: correo,
    direccion: direccion,
    telefono: telefono,
    tarjeta: tarjeta,
    fechaEX: fechaEX
  }
  arrayDatos.push(item);
  return item;
}

const EliminarDB = () => {
  let data;
  arrayDatos.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element.nombre === nombre) {
          data = index;
    }
  })

  arrayDatos.splice(data,1)
  GuardarDB();
}

container_Datos.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data_borrar = e.path[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
  if(e.target.innerHTML === 'Borrar datos'){
    EliminarDB();
  }
```

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil usar JSON.stringify para guardar los datos y JSON.parse para obtenerlos y modificarlos?

Comment: Así los tengo, pero no publique esa parte por olvido jaja de igual forma gracias por tu ayuda amigo, ya pude solucionar el problema, abajo ya lo respondí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene pinta que no le pasas el parámetro nombre a la funcion `EliminarDB`

```
const EliminarDB = (nombre) => {
  let data;
  arrayDatos.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element.nombre === nombre) {
          data = index;
    }
  })

  arrayDatos.splice(data,1)
  GuardarDB();
}


 EliminarDB('Luis');
```

Comment: Buenas compañero, gracias por el consejo y ya pude arreglar el problema, al pasarle el parámetro ''nombre'' la condicional donde hacia la verificación en ''EliminarDB'' de comparar los nombres estaba mal, porque en la función donde muestro los datos a pantalla (Esa parte no la coloque por olvido), estaba así por ejemplo ''containerDatos += `<p>NC: ${element.nombre}</p>`;", el problema era que me contaba el ''NC:'', y lo arregle añadiendole un ''substr()'' en la función de eliminar para que si comparara bien los nombres, de igual forma gracias ya que no estaba seguro sobre del parámetro